# 'on raise' hook in ruby

Tags: ruby, hook

Is there a way to hook in some code after any `raise` is done in ruby?  The idea is to provide some extra information about the error in a centralized location, such as follows:

```
def after_raise
  logger.error "some information here"
end

def logger
  @logger ||= Logger.new(my_log_output)
end
```

Edit:  Maybe it will help if I'm more specific about what this is for.

I'm working a large project with multiple domains.  There are times that raised errors are just not descriptive enough - today I was talking with one of my team-members and we discussed ways to work around this.  It's not that the original raise messages are awful/completely nondescript (although, I'm sure that's the case in one or two places), just that as the project has evolved, new information has become useful for troubleshooting.  We'd like to create something that can extend existing code.

Each domain is able to be tested alone, but plugs into an overall infrastructure.  If we added this to the 'main' domain, when the application as a whole is running (for example, during end-to-end tests) this would be applied to all instances where `raise` is called.  If we were testing a single domain, it would not apply.

Comment: Use a `begin ... rescue` block to catch the exception and do something with it.

Comment: You are entering [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) area here. The best implementation of AOP in ruby is [Aquarium](https://github.com/deanwampler/Aquarium).

Comment: Is the callback really supposed to be executed upon any `raise`, i.e. even if the exception was rescued?

Comment: You could implement something really dirty by just aliasing `Kernel#raise` and creating a new raise method but you should really consider why you need this functionality first. e.g. `module Kernel; alias_method :old_raise, :raise; def raise(*args); @logger ||= Logger.new(my_output_file); @logger.error "Raised Here"; old_raise(*args); end; end`

Comment: `ensure` is more hook-like than `rescue`, I'd think.

Comment: FYI, exceptions aren't necessarily errors. For example, I could try to open a file (and catch any resulting errors) as a way of checking whether I have sufficient permissions to access it. The fact that an exception was raised in that case isn't necessarily something I want to log. Raise/rescue is just another control structure, just like if/else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the `Kernel#raise` method, keeping the original method through an alias:

```
module Kernel
  alias_method :_raise, :raise # original method is now _raise

  def raise(*args)
    # do hook stuff
    _raise(*args)
  end
end
```

Comment: that could work, it's a bit....mmm, idk.  I'll see if anything else comes along, but +1 in the meantime